# Java threads : ExecutorService delay between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I know the traditional way to delay a thread by using sleep method. My question is supposedly i have the following:

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

Is there a way say by using ExecutorService class to have a delay between each threads without using sleep method? I mean is there a method in ExecutorService  class for this purpose?

Comment: Whjat do you mean by "delay of between each threads"?  Do you delays between exection of each submitted task?

Comment: Could you name a reason for the delay? Most of the time you would have the Runnables / Futures use some kind of blocking instead. Furthermore, what functionality do you require that makes sleep() not fit for use?

Comment: The class documentation has nothing listed. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: @skaffman Not really. I mean say the first thread goes in and run and i want the second thread to run after 10 seconds. I dont want the delay to be control in the run method of runnable object. Rather i want ExecutorServcie to submit the 2 thread 10 seconds later after the first

Comment: I think you can use ScheduledExecutorService (which is subinterface of ExecutorService) 'scheduleAtFixedRate' method will allow to specify the delay.

Comment: @yapkm01: Thhe executor doesn't "submit threads", it submits tasks, usually to pre-existing threads. It's not clear what you're asking here because of the confusing terminology.

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean something like

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If you want three tasks, 10 seconds apart you can do

```
service.execute(task1);
service.schedule(task2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
service.schedule(task3, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I think the above will cause a periodic delay on a particular task - meaning the same task is run at a periodic period. What i want is a delay between tasks for example task 1 (runnable obj1) ran first and task 2 (runnable obj2) starts running after 10 seconds runnable obj1 has been submitted. I'm wondering if this can be done using the ExecutorService or some sort ..